# sql server query group

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

```
code  name   value
1     aaa    15
2     bbb    18
1     aaa    17
1     aaa    16
```

I need select items group by code. Result must be:

```
1   aaa   15,17,16
2   bbb   18
```

Comment: Which SQL Server version?

Comment: it is MS Sql Server 2012

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv

Answer (score 0):

You need `string_agg` as follows:

```
Select code, name,
       String_agg(value,',') within group (order by value) as val
  From t
 Group by code, name
```

Comment: it is MS Sql Server 2012

Answer (score 0):

If you have a maximum of two values, you can use aggregation:

```
select code, name,
       (case when count(*) > 1 then concat(min(value), ',', max(value))
             else min(value)
        end)
from t
group by code, name;
```